# For the program mentioned above I am getting runtime error for one test case. All the remaining test cases are passed. Any suggestions

Tags: java

```
class Result {

   public static String findDay(int month, int day, int year) {
         String [] B = {"MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"}; 
     Calendar A = Calendar.getInstance();
     A.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
     A.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
     A.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
     return B[A.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-2];
      }

}
```

I am getting run time error for the code mentioned above for one of the test cases. I don't understand why, can you please explain me how to resolve this kind of run time errors in the future.

Comment: what is the error? Post a [mcve]

Comment: And what is the test case?

Comment: Hint: what if Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK returns 1?

Comment: @Reimeus I am getting runtime error and date for the test case is 02/29/2004.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that might me the problem, I willl try to modify the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet if I modify the code, I am getting the wrong day, for wednesday its showing like thursday. any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you all for the info, I forgot to subtract 1 from the day of the month.

Comment: @user8702827 for us to know how to fix the code we have to know what the code is supposed to do and what inputs it expects.

Comment: That suggests you're only modifying one part of your code. Hint: how do you expect to currently every return "SUNDAY"? That has index 6, which suggests that `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` would have to return 8.

Comment: Additionally "runtime error" isn't a complete description. What *exactly* is happening? If it's an exception (as I expect) you should include the stack trace as part of your [mcve].

Comment: I have modifed 2 parts of the code, along with the month , i also kept day_of_week -1 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in this code, the both are about indexes.
I propose this version :

```
    public static String findDay(int month, int day, int year) {
    String [] B = {"MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"}; 
    Calendar A = Calendar.getInstance();

    final int monthIndex = (month + 11) % 12;
    A.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthIndex);
    A.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    A.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);

    final int dayIndex = (A.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 5) % 7;
    return B[dayIndex];
}
```

As you can see, I use the modulo to still in indexes range of your Array "B". I do the same for the "month index".